# Trouble with Equations for 2D projectile motion WITH air resistance?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

My AP students are learning 2D kinematics, and it got me in the mood to play around with projectiles WITH air resistance, just for fun because we always neglect it, and so that I can maybe show them when the unit is over.

I understand the flow of the process for deriving the formulas, and I found a site that goes through a toy model of it where the drag is directly proportional to the velocity:
[http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/lectures/node29.html#:~:text=Suppose%2C%20further%2C%20that%2C%20in,proportional%20to%20its%20instantaneous%20speed](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/lectures/node29.html#:%7E:text=Suppose%2C%20further%2C%20that%2C%20in,proportional%20to%20its%20instantaneous%20speed).

In the derivation, the equation for the $x$-position at time $t$ is

[image]

and the equation for the $y$-position at time $t$ is

[image]

If these came from my own derivation, I wouldn't trust them too much, but the site seemed to be pretty good and thorough, so I used these formulas in a Google Sheet (Excel) document so I could get a table of $x$ and $y$ values that I could graph.

But when I did so, I got this:

[image]

[NOTE: In the equations, I replace ViCos(theta) and ViSin(theta) with Vix and Viy because I break the initial velocity into components in a different cell on the doc, to make it a bit simpler to write.]

The "X" and "Y" data tables are the normal values you'd get from the kinematic formulas if you ignore air drag. That data is correct and graphs a correct trajectory.

But the other two data tables that use the more involved formulas result in a data that graphs an exponentially increasing curve. That's definitely not how it should look.

My first assumption was that I input the formula wrong... but I checked multiple times and it seems right.

So I went to Desmos to graph the y-positions versus time and got this:

[image]

This should make a graph that starts at zero, reaches a max, then goes back to zero, yet it only increases.

Between Desmos and Google Sheets, I feel like I'm not entering the formulas in wrong because the results from both are wrong but are consistent and corroborate each other.

So my choices are:

- The formulas are wrong
- The formulas are right and I entered them incorrectly
- The formulas are right and I entered them correctly, but I'm missing a step or some knowledge

Any suggestions and help are very appreciated. Thank you for taking the time to read this!!!

Comment: This site isn't really keen on 'check-my-work' questions, which this question really is.

Comment: @Gert      I'm sorry about that. It's the only site I know where I might find people who could answer something like this. Do you know of any more appropriate forums?

Comment: You might also want to consult this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance

Comment: @Gert    Oh wow, looks promising, thank you!

Comment: *If these came from my own derivation, I wouldn't trust them too much, but the site seemed to be pretty good and thorough.* You should check the solution to see whether it satisfies the right differential equation and the right initial conditions. If it does, it’s correct. In that case you have a programming problem, not a physics problem.

Comment: Unless you are considering something the size of a dust particle in air, drag is not proportional to velocity, but to velocity squared. Unfortunately, that makes the differential equations harder to solve analytically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is taking $g$ and $v_t$ to be negative. The assumptions behind this solution are that the gravitational acceleration is $-g\hat z$ and the terminal velocity is $-v_t\hat z$. These negative signs make the directions correct for positive $g$ and $v_t$.

The equation of motion is

$$\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=-g\hat{z}-\frac{g}{v_t}\vec{v}.$$

Again, you can see here that $g$ and $v_t$ are positive. The downward direction of gravity and the fact that the drag force is in the opposite direction from the velocity are taken into account by explicit negative signs, not by letting parameters be implicitly negative.